# how should I create good rest api?

Tags: python, rest

to get posts for a user:
GET http://test.com/users/123/posts or GET http://test.com/posts?user_id=123

to get new posts count:
GET http://test.com/posts/count/new or http://test.com/new_posts_count or others?

Answer (score 2):

This is a good read: http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api.

And in terms of the two formats you suggested: I prefer the former.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter from a REST point of view (REST doesn't define URI structure). The client should not know the URL structure before hand so technically it doesn't matter to the client either.

I personally prefer the first style as I think it makes more sense when you have a resource hierarchy. It also allows a client to move back up a URI by simply chopping off the end resource, similar to how you can go back up a directory on a file system by simply clicking the parent button.

But there is no "right answer" to this from a REST point of view. REST is concerned with the transfer of state of resources, not the resource hierarchy or URI definition.